# Issues with installing Devectorize package in Julia

Tags: package, julia, vectorization

I wanted to install the [devectorize package in Julia](https://juliapackages.com/p/devectorize), but I'm having an issue. I run

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add Devectorize
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
* Devectorize (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

I have also tried

```
Pkg.add("Devectorize")
```

With the same result. Is Devectorize no longer supported?

Comment: Devectorize.jl is no longer supported and no longer needed. In addition to the blog post linked by @OscarSmith, you can read about broadcasting and dot syntax in the Julia manual, https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting and https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devectorize was only beneficial to Julia before version 0.6. Since then, vectorized expressions are automatically fused. For more info, you should check out this blog post from when the feature was added. https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots/